# Does it make sense to use type hints in a function which can return parameters of different type?

Tags: python, types

I want to check if a string contains a substring matchings the regexp `_\d{2}.` (i.e., `_`, two digits and then `.`), and if it does, return the numeric part. The following code does this:

```
def extract_digits(string: str) -> int:
    match = re.search(r'_\d{2}\.', string)
    if match is not None:    
        digits = match.group(0)[1:3]
        n = int(digits)
    else:
        n = None
    return n
```

As it can be verified by testing it on these strings:

```
wrong = "resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5"
right = "resnet50_csv_24.h5"
```

However, I wonder if it makes sense to use a type hint for the output, since it can be either `NoneType` or `int`. Note that the downstream code handles the `None` return value gracefully, thus my doubt is not whether this function will crash my code or not. My only perplexity is that neither the linter or the interpreter seem to care at all about the fact that the return parameter may or may not have type `int`.

I think that's consistent with the idea of type hints (they're hints for the developer, not directives for the interpreter). But then, am I being Pythonic in using type hints and then ignoring them?

Comment: It makes sense if you type hint it correctly, using a `Union` of some sort ... Not exactly sure what you are even asking. And obviously, the interpreter doesn't care. I'm not sure which linters might or might not integrate type hints, but if you had used `mypy` it would complain about your incorrectly typed function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ooooh, `mypy` looks great! Thanks for the library recommendation ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a hint for that function, you should use [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional):

```
from typing import Optional

def extract_digits(string: str) -> Optional[int]:
    match = re.search(r'_\d{2}\.', string)
    if match is not None:    
        digits = match.group(0)[1:3]
        n = int(digits)
    else:
        n = None
    return n
```

Comment: yes, I'd like to use hints, indeed, in which case `Optional` is the perfect answer, as you notice. However, if you have other suggestions other than using hints, I'm listening.

Comment: @DeltaIV Well there's the more general [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), so you could use `Union[int, None]` (in fact [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) is just a shorthand for that, as mentioned in the documentation). Not sure what else you could use.

Comment: well, no, if one stays with type hints, then  `typing.Optional` is clearly the best (readable & coincise) choice. I thought you were hinting (heh :-) to using something else than type hints, but I misunderstood you.